# Tag Helper forms: asp-for not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

Thanks for the help so far. I've worked to make sure everything else works so I can focus on this problem. I'm still convinced it'll be an easy fix once we've cracked it. I have the following code, sorry I changed it so much, I had to start again after I made a real mess of the last one without taking a backup.

```
        public IActionResult Index()
    {

        if(IndexModel.GlobalTasks == null)
        {
            IndexModel initModel = new IndexModel();
            initModel.AllTasks = InitList();
            initModel.EmptyTask = new ToDoTask();
            IndexModel.GlobalTasks = initModel.AllTasks;
        }
        IndexModel model = new IndexModel();
        model.AllTasks = IndexModel.GlobalTasks;
        model.EmptyTask = new ToDoTask("");
        return View(model);
    }
    //Create Task
    public IActionResult Create(ToDoTask indexModel)
    {
        IndexModel.GlobalTasks.Add(indexModel);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

And:

```
@model DE.Models.IndexModel
<h2>To Do List</h2>
<form asp-action="Create">
    <input asp-for="EmptyTask" value="@Model.EmptyTask" />
    <input asp-for="EmptyTask.TaskDetails" placeholder="New Task" />
    <button type="submit">Add Task</button>
</form>
```

The good news is this creates a new ToDoTask. So the Controller code must be pretty close to spot on. The problem is the View is passing null details to the controller, so I'm getting an empty Task, which isn't what I want. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try debugging to see what the error is and where it occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller action expects a `ToDoTask` object while your view uses a `TaskViewModel` object.

Try using the same type in both of them.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Using Tag Helper forms:

```html
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
    
<section >
    <input type="text" asp placeholder="Title" asp-for="MyWork.Title"/>
</section >
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Create()` method you need to instantiate the `ToDoTask` object, I think. So try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(ToDoTask newTask)
{
    newTask = new ToDoTask(); 

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

You may also need to return the `ToDoTask` object.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but it's not done the trick. I instantiated the object and tried returning it, as you suggested, but we're getting getting a response with a status of 500.